# Postfix error on Centos 7 - Fatal: the Postfix mail system is already running

Tags: postfix, centos7

I am having an error at the postfix service in CentOS 7.

```
[root@iZ237ak0745Z postfix]# systemctl status postfix.service
● postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-11-18 04:07:59 CST; 34min ago
Process: 6022 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postfix start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 6017 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postfix/chroot-update (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 6013 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postfix/aliasesdb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 18 04:07:58 iZ237ak0745Z systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
Nov 18 04:07:59 iZ237ak0745Z postfix/postfix-script[6029]: fatal: the Postfix mail system is already running
Nov 18 04:07:59 iZ237ak0745Z systemd[1]: postfix.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 18 04:07:59 iZ237ak0745Z systemd[1]: Failed to start Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
Nov 18 04:07:59 iZ237ak0745Z systemd[1]: Unit postfix.service entered failed state.
Nov 18 04:07:59 iZ237ak0745Z systemd[1]: postfix.service failed.
```

So, Can anyone tell me why am I getting `postfix/postfix-script[6029]: fatal: the Postfix mail system is already running` ?

After run `ps aux | grep postfix`

```
root      5756  0.0  0.1  91700  2232 ?        Ss   04:04   0:00    /usr/libexec/postfix/master -w
postfix   5759  0.0  0.2  91872  4056 ?        S    04:04   0:00 qmgr -l -t unix -u
postfix   7782  0.0  0.2  91804  4032 ?        S    09:05   0:00 pickup -l -t unix -u
root      7798  0.0  0.0 110216   904 pts/0    S+   09:29   0:00 grep --color=auto postfix
```

Comment: Because, it is already running!

Comment: Oh really?Sorry I am a noob here. But why it shows <code>Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-11-18 04:07:59 CST; 34min ago here</code>?

Answer (score -2):

please execute

'kill -9 5756 5759 7782 7798'
'systemctl start postfix'
'systemctl status postfix' you should see its running